# Как создать Android web приложение?

Tags: android, google-play

Есть Android Studio. Скопированный сайт. Задача сделать мобильное приложение на основе сайта?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо в разметку добавить `WebView`, а в него загрузить HTML из папки `app/src/assets` примерно так:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

где `data` - HTML в виде строки, полученной программно из `assets`.

Может ещё пара манипуляций с `WebView` понадобиться. Например включить JS. Примерно так:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

---

Но тут надо учитывать, что такое приложение мало полезно в большинстве случаев. Например, в PlayMarket его выложить будет нельзя. Это запрещено ([en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31194912/3212712), [документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps)) правилами оного.

Comment: Без webview не обойтись? За ответ спасибо!

Comment: @Evgeniy, в теории можно и без него. Можно на стандартных контролах реализовать весь функционал сайта. Но это будет на порядки дольше. Зато качественно. Однако, без деталей и ТЗ сложно что-то ещё сказать.